# Dynamically define csv table structure based on HTTP request body in Logic apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

So, I have a logic app that looks like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUTEf.png)

The main idea of the app is to get the list items of a list and copy the contents in a csv file in blob storage.

The site name and list name are passed through the HTTP request body.

However, I would like to also define the Select operation column mapping dynamically.

The body looks like this

```
{
"listName" : "The list name",
"siteAddress" : "SharepointSiteAddress",  
"columns" : {  
"Email": " @item()?['Employee']?['Email']",
"Region": " @item()?['Region']?['Value']"
}
}
```

In the 'Map' section of the 'Select' Operation I use the 'columns' property as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lUfU.png)

However, in the output stream of the 'Select' Operation, email and region column values are resolved with the string that is passed instead of retrieving the actual item value that I am trying to refer to.

Can I somehow create the csv table dynamically through the HTTP request while also being able to access the items' values?

Answer (score 0):

Using expressions, you can create CSV file with Dynamic data. I have reproduced issue from my side and below are the stepts I followed.

1. Created Logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In Http trigger, I have defined sample payload as shown below,

```
{
"listName" : "The list name",
"siteAddress" : "SharepointSiteAddress",  
"columns" : {  
"Email": " Email",
"DisplayName": "DisplayName"
}
}
```

[image]

3. In select action, from is taken from Get items value. In Map row, key is taken from Http trigger and value is from SharePoint item as shown below,
   [image]
   **Map:**
   Key -**triggerBody()?['columns']?['Email']**
   Value - **item()?['Editor']?['Email']**
4. Output of Get Items action in my case is like below. Hence written expression according to that.

```
"value": [
{
"@odata.etag": "\"1\"",
"ItemInternalId": "3",
"ID": 3,
"Modified": "2022-11-15T10:49:47Z",
"Editor": {
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
"Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|xyzt.com",
"DisplayName": "Test",
"Email": "v@mail.com",
"JobTitle": ""
}
```

5. Tested logic app. It ran successfully and csv file is generated like below,
   [image]
   Csv file:
   [image]

Comment: thank you for your answer @vijaya. However, what I'm looking for is a way to fully rely on the columns property of the request body. Ideally this app could also be used for copying another SharePoint list that contains more columns and/or different column names.
So I would like to fully define the column structure along with what values to be used using the body only.